# in StarUML How to copy plain text from other applications?

Tags: uml, tool-uml, staruml

I want to copy some plain text(such as method name, class name , comments) to StarUML , but ctrl+v does not work. Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl-V. Ctrl-P is for printing.